# Generate report from form to confirm before submit

Tags: javascript, forms, report, confirm

I have form with checkboxes (in fact with radio buttons instead of checkboxes). I want to create a report with a list of checked options. This report should be confirmed befor submit form. How to do this? There are two other functions already in my code. My form looks similar to form below

```html
<form method="POST" action="add.php" onSubmit="return otherFunction();">
 <?php
while($linia=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
  echo "<tr><td>".$linia['Description']."</td><td><input type='radio' name='check".$i."' value='1' onClick='activeFunction(".$i.")'><input type='hidden' name='vcheck".$i."' value='".$linia['Id_description']."'></td>"; 
}
<button type='submit'>Send form</button>
?>
```

I need it to work like that: Somebody checks some of this radio buttons then click submit then this person should see checked options to read it and confirm if there is no mistakes ex. he/she didn't check one of options he wanted

Answer (score 0):

I would place the function-call on the button like this:

```
<button onClick="otherFunction()">Send Form</button>
<script>
function otherFunction() {
    if (confirm('Sure you want to submit the form?')) {
         // you'd have to give you form an id like 'myform' first
         document.getElementById('myform').submit();
    }
    else {
         // not sending the form, maybe do something else here
    }

}
</script>
```

Your form-tag should then look like this:

```
<form method="POST" action="add.php" id="myform">
```

Comment: I need to have a list of checked radio buttons, not only window which asks me if I confirm

Comment: Well, you already got your list of radio-buttons!? Then I might have missunderstood your question.
What is the problem then?

Comment: I need it to work like that: Somebody checks some of this radio buttons then click submit then this person should see checked options to read it and confirm if there is no mistakes ex. he/she didn't check one of options he wanted